# How to add a profile photo to a contact as you create it via google contact People API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

**Update/Solution**

There isn't a way to add a photo to a person object on creating a contact via People API. However you can updated the photo directly after using People.People.updateContactPhoto. updateContactPhoto has a limit of 60 queries per minute per user. If your script needs to update more than 60 contact photos, then you will need to add a delay in your code so that query limit isn't reached

**Question:**

I am creating a large list of contacts from a set of data, including contact photos for each contact. When I create contacts via people.createContact, if I have the photos field there it states "person.photos is a read only field." How I can I create the contact with a profile photo link as well?

Example Code

```
const contact = {names:..., addresses:..., emailAddressess:..., phoneNumbers:..., 
  photos: {"url":..., "primary": true}
}

People.People.createContact(contact)
```

this gives the error message
[image: Error Message]

**Update 1:**
Currently this is what I'm doing and it works. The main problem now is I don't want to use the Utilities.Sleep function. I'm looping over this function hundreds of times, and that adds up quickly. If I don't use the sleep though around the 40th or 50th contact it throws an "Internal error encountered". The contact it errors on is different each time, so the error is not tied to a specific person. My assumption is the error comes from running too many requests too quickly, but how can I run this without forcing it to sleep?

```
function importPerson(person){
  const photoData = encodePhotoData(person.photos[0].url)
  delete person.photos

  const newContact = People.People.createContact(person)
  
  People.People.updateContactPhoto({ 
    photoBytes: photoData,
  },newContact.resourceName)

  //This stops it from throwing an error
  Utilities.sleep(1000)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [people.updateContactPhoto](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContactPhoto) to update a contact's person. You need to convert your photo's url into a raw photo bytes in base64-encoded string.

### Sample Code:

```
  var resource = {
   names: [
     {
       givenName: "Sample1"
     }
   ],
   emailAddresses: [
     {
       value: "sample1@example.com"
     }
   ]
 };
  //create contact
  var response = People.People.createContact(resource);

  //Get raw photo bytes in base64-encoded string
  var url = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T_wVWLlmg7w/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABa8/00gzXvDBYqw/s100/photo.jpg"
  var photoBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var base64EncodedBytes = Utilities.base64Encode(photoBlob.getBlob().getBytes()); 

  var photoResource = {
    photoBytes: base64EncodedBytes
  }
  //update photo
  People.People.updateContactPhoto(photoResource,response.resourceName)
```

### Output:

[image]

---

### (UPDATE)

Here is the sample code where I tried to create 100 contacts:

```
function testContact(){
  for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
      var resource = {
    names: [
      {
        givenName: "Sample1"
      }
    ],
    emailAddresses: [
      {
        value: "sample1@example.com"
      }
    ],
    photos:[
      {
        url: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T_wVWLlmg7w/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABa8/00gzXvDBYqw/s100/photo.jpg"
      }
    ]
  };
    Logger.log(i);
    importPerson(resource);
  }
}

function importPerson(person){
  const photoData = encodePhotoData(person.photos[0].url)
  delete person.photos

  const newContact = People.People.createContact(person)
  
  People.People.updateContactPhoto({ 
    photoBytes: photoData,
  },newContact.resourceName)

  //This stops it from throwing an error
  //Utilities.sleep(1000)
}
```

Comment: This is one of those cases where the old editor provides a lot more information than the new editor.  I was wondering how you knew that the updateContactPhoto() required two parameters until I looked at the old editor.  Thanks.  I played around with this earlier but decided I'd wait until someone that used it before answered.

Comment: Ahh I just saw the note on the image spec about the base 64 encoding.  Thanks for the info I really like learning new things.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback, regarding the new editor parameters, for most advanced google services I normally check the actual api reference first to now how many parameters i might expect. Then I type the command and wait for the parameter suggestion in the new editor :) `updateContactPhoto(resource: Peopleapi_v1.Peopleapi.V1.Schema.UpdateContactPhotoRequest, resourceName: string):`

Comment: I just enabled the People API and it took a while for the editor to update itself with the information for that API I guess.  I guess I should have been more patient.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I ended up doing, although I wish it would be possible to add when creating the contact. Do you know how to fix the error of Internal error encountered when running this across all of my contacts?

Comment: Hi @DavidWestwood, can you share your updated code snippet?

Comment: @RonM I just edited my post with the new snippet!

Comment: Hi @DavidWestwood, I tried to run the solution i provided in a loop of 100. But I did not encountered such error

Comment: I also test your sample code in a loop of 100 without sleep using the same inputs i used in my answer. But I also did not encountered such error. Creation of contact and update of photo was successful

Comment: What inputs did you use? My contacts have a range of around 20 different photos that it could be using, is the problem tied to constantly switching photos used? Also, I realized I didn't give context to the encodePhotoData function. It is simply using 

`const photoBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(photo_url).getBlob(); 
return Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(photoBlob.getBytes())`

Comment: Yes, i just converted your url into a 64encodedbytes. I used the resource and photo url in the answer provided. Then call the function 100 times see the updated answer

Comment: I'll try to use 20 different photos as well and see if i will encounter the issue. I would appreciate it if you could share a sample photo? I would like to know the resolution/dimension of the photo used to see if there's an impact

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232426/discussion-between-david-westwood-and-ron-m).